# Write partly tab-delimited data to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, regex, bash

I have a MySQL-Database with 7 Columns (`chr`, `pos`, `num`, `iA`, `iB`, `iC`, `iD`) and a file that contains 40 million lines each containing a dataset. Each line has 4 tab delimited columns, whereas the first three columns always contain data, and the fourth column can contain up to three different `key=value` pairs separated by a semicolon

```
chr   pos   num   info
1     10203 3     iA=0.34;iB=nerv;iC=45;iD=dskf12586
1     10203 4     iA=0.44;iC=45;iD=dsf12586;iB=nerv
1     10203 5     
1     10213 1     iB=nerv;iC=49;iA=0.14;iD=dskf12586
1     10213 2     iA=0.34;iB=nerv;iD=cap1486
1     10225 1     iD=dscf12586
```

The key=value pairs in the column info have no specific order. I'm also not sure if a key can occur twice (I hope not).

I'd like to write the data into the database. The first three columns are no problem, but extractiong the values from the info-columns puzzles me, since the key=value pairs are unordered and not every key has to be in the line.
For a similar dataset (with ordered info-Column) I used a java-Programm in connection with regular expressions, which allowed me to (1) check and (2) extract data, but now I'm stranded.

How can I resolve this task, preferably with a bash-script or directly in MySQL?

Comment: What about using PHP ?

Comment: Sorry, this could be done in almost any language :p What I would do is the following: Loop through every line, split by `\t+` (tab(s)). *split* the last tab by `;`, and split again by `=`. Now you have the values of *info* you just have to create the logic behind it and create a query and execute it.

Answer (score 2):

You did not mention exactly how you want to write the data. But the below example with `awk` shows how you can get each individual id and key in each line. instead of the `printf`, you can use your own logic to write data

```
[[bash_prompt$]]$ cat test.sh; echo "###########"; awk -f test.sh log
{
  if(length($4)) {
    split($4,array,";");
    print "In " $1, $2, $3;
    for(element in array) {
      key=substr(array[element],0,index(array[element],"="));
      value=substr(array[element],index(array[element],"=")+1);
      printf("found %s key and %s value for %d line from %s\n",key,value,NR,array[element]);
    }
  }
}
###########
In 1 10203 3
found iD= key and dskf12586 value for 1 line from iD=dskf12586
found iA= key and 0.34 value for 1 line from iA=0.34
found iB= key and nerv value for 1 line from iB=nerv
found iC= key and 45 value for 1 line from iC=45
In 1 10203 4
found iB= key and nerv value for 2 line from iB=nerv
found iA= key and 0.44 value for 2 line from iA=0.44
found iC= key and 45 value for 2 line from iC=45
found iD= key and dsf12586 value for 2 line from iD=dsf12586
In 1 10213 1
found iD= key and dskf12586 value for 4 line from iD=dskf12586
found iB= key and nerv value for 4 line from iB=nerv
found iC= key and 49 value for 4 line from iC=49
found iA= key and 0.14 value for 4 line from iA=0.14
In 1 10213 2
found iA= key and 0.34 value for 5 line from iA=0.34
found iB= key and nerv value for 5 line from iB=nerv
found iD= key and cap1486 value for 5 line from iD=cap1486
In 1 10225 1
found iD= key and dscf12586 value for 6 line from iD=dscf12586
```

Answer (score 2):

Awk solution from @abasu with inserts that also solves the unordered key-value pairs.

parse.awk :

```
NR>1 {
  col["iA"]=col["iB"]=col["iC"]=col["iD"]="null";

  if(length($4)) {
    split($4,array,";");
    for(element in array) {
      split(array[element],keyval,"=");
      col[keyval[1]] = "'" keyval[2] "'";
    }
  }
  print "INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (" $1 "," $2 "," $3 "," col["iA"] "," col["iB"] "," col["iC"] "," col["iD"] ");";
}
```

Test/run :

```
$ awk -f parse.awk file
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (1,10203,3,'0.34','nerv','45','dskf12586');
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (1,10203,4,'0.44','nerv','45','dsf12586');
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (1,10203,5,null,null,null,null);
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (1,10213,1,'0.14','nerv','49','dskf12586');
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (1,10213,2,'0.34','nerv',null,'cap1486');
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (1,10225,1,null,null,null,'dscf12586');
```